# QGraphicsView/QGraphicsScene rendering glitches

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qt4.8

Let’s say I add an image to a scene and a line such that one of its endpoint is precisely on one of the corners of a pixel. When I zoom in or out the view I see that the endpoint of the line shifts relative to the background image.. As I change the zoom level the difference varies. If I add more lines or ellipsis, they don’t move relative to one another.

Is it a bug or I don’t use something properly?

I use Qt4.8 shipped with Ubuntu 12.04 running in VMWare Player.

Comment: Have you setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing) on your view?

Comment: Or setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform)

Comment: @Sosukodo, I fiddled with it, but it didn’t help.

Comment: I can only suggest showing a small (compilable) code example along with a screenshot of what you're seeing.